# SSAS - unable to establish connection 08001

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssas, olap-cube

I'm a beginner in Microsoft BI technology. I'm studying SSAS and have a problem of connection establishing with SQL server when I tried to process a BI cube project.

I use SQL Server 2012 and visual studio 2013 for my project.

My project process always failed with the first message was:

---

OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not supported on the client.; 08001.

---

Here are some solution I have tried after I did the research from internet but it's not working:

1. Try to unblock firewall (Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174937.aspx)
2. Try to use either "Use Window Authentication" or "Use SQL Server Authentication" in Connection Manager when I set up a data source for my Cube project. 
   [image]

So could anyone have a idea for my problem? Thanks in advance. 
p/s: Sorry for my bad English!!

Answer (score 0):

when you select the windows authentication (or give sql server authentication), does it populates all the databases available on the given server? If yes , then when you select a db , click on test connection , is it successful? if not , then are you connecting to remote db server i.e your bids project server and database server are different? The user has access rights on database server?
Also check what user account analysis services is using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. All test connections are succeeded. For your question "The user has access rights on database server? Also check what user account analysis services is using?", how can i verify it?

Comment: When i launch visual studio and ssms, i always run as administrator.

Comment: go to services.msc and search for sql server analysis services and then check log on as for user account of analysis services.